# дубликаты писем при отправке в цикле через compose() d yii2

Tags: yii2

в цикле вызываю

```
foreach ($recipient as $n => $user){
   $mailer->sendMail($user->email,$params[$n]);
}
```

если продампить, то получается так:

```
$mailer->sendMail(test@es.net.ua,$params[77])
$mailer->sendMail(test2@es.net.ua,$params[207])
$mailer->sendMail(test2@es.net.ua,$params[299])
$mailer->sendMail(sell@es.net.ua,$params[77])
$mailer->sendMail(sell@es.net.ua,$params[207])
$mailer->sendMail(sell@es.net.ua,$params[299])
```

т.е. все абсолютно верно, но функция sendMail

```
public function sendMail($email, $params = []){
//        $c[$email] = $params;
//        echo '<pre>';
//        print_r($this);
//        echo '</pre>';
        try{
            if (!isset($params['site_url'])) {
                $params['site_url'] = Yii::getAlias('@webfront');
            }



            $replaceParams = [];
            foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
                if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $replaceParams['{'.$key.'}'] = $value;
            }

            $this->body = str_replace(array_keys($replaceParams), array_values($replaceParams), $this->body);
            $this->title = str_replace(array_keys($replaceParams), array_values($replaceParams), $this->title);



            if (isset($params['user_id']) && $params['user_id'] > 0) {
                Notification::create($params['user_id'], $this->body, $this->title, $params['notification_url'] ?? null);
            }

            \Yii::$app->mailer->htmlLayout = "@common/mail/layouts/html";
            \Yii::$app->mailer->textLayout = "@common/mail/layouts/text";
            $sent = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose(
                    [
                        'html' => "@common/mail/views/main-html",
                        'text' => '@common/mail/views/main-text'
                    ], 
                    [
                        'htmlbody' => $this->body, 
                        'textbody' => $this->body,
                    ])
                    ->setTo($email)
                    ->setFrom(\Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
                    ->setSubject($this->title);
//                    ->setHtmlBody($this->body);
            if(isset($params['file_check']))
                $sent->attach($params['file_check']);
            if(isset($params['file_products']))
                $sent->attach($params['file_products']);

//            $sent->getSwiftMessage()
//                ->getHeaders()
//                ->addTextHeader('List-Unsubscribe', \Yii::getAlias('@webfront/unsubscribe/' . $email) );
            $sent->send();
            unset($email);
            unset ($params);
            if (!$sent) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Sending error.');
            }

        }
        catch (\Exception $e){
            AppHelper::log($e->getMessage());
//            var_dump($e);
        }
    }
```

вместо того, чтоб отправить 6 разных писем отправляет 6 одинаковых писем на указанные ящики. Т.е. проблема в том, что несмотря на то, что $params[$key] передаётся верно, письма всё равно все одинаковые, используют $params[77].

Как я понимаю при вызове функции в цикле ей передаются параметры ОДНОГО конкретного письма и она вызывается до тех пор, пока не отправит все письма по одному, поэтому нет необходимости прикручивать `Yii::$app->mailer->sendMultiple($messages);` т.к. это будет костылём.

Если в самой функции продампить приходящие параметры ($email, $params), то получаю их накопленными вместо того, чтоб получить последний, переданный из цикла, т.е. например вот так `$user->email`:

```
test@es.net.ua
test2@es.net.ua
test2@es.net.ua
sell@es.net.ua
sell@es.net.ua
sell@es.net.ua
```

с `$params[$key]` тоже самое, только получаю 6 массивов.

unset() данных после отправки не помогает.

Помогите понять, почему дубли. Хостер открещивается, говорит лимит стоит в 6 писем в секунду. Этого должно хватать. Пробовал в цикле slepp(), тоже не помогает. Короче хелп.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите взор на свой цикл:

```
foreach ($recipient as $n => $user){
   $mailer->sendMail($user->email,$params[$key]);
}
```

Переменная $key берется не из массив $recipient. Полагаю, что должна использоваться $n или $user.

Comment: да, я опечатался в вопросе, там $n: foreach ($recipient as $n => $user){
   $mailer->sendMail($user->email,$params[$n]);
} И проблема именно с таким циклом, в котором $params[$n]

Answer (score 0):

Для начала надо код привести в порядок, а не пихать все в один метод. Тогда будет проще найти ошибку. Полагаю, что загвоздка в том, что данные письма хранятся в свойствах объекта. И когда в первый раз кеи заменились на значения, второй раз уже заменять нечего.

```
        $this->body = str_replace(array_keys($replaceParams), array_values($replaceParams), $this->body);
        $this->title = str_replace(array_keys($replaceParams), array_values($replaceParams), $this->title);
```

Вероятно измененный шаблон письма надо хранить в переменной внутри метода.

Comment: ход мысли понятен, однако независимо от того в $this хранятся данные письма или в переменной внутри метода непонятно одно: каким образом переменные из одной итерации цикла влияют на эти же переменные при второй итерации. Я вызвал в первой итерации функцию, передал параметры, она должна отработать и в "чистом виде" вызваться второй итерацией цикла, но получается, что после первой отработки она получает новые параметры не как новые, а вдобавок к старым. Может целесообразно не $this трогать, а очищать все после отправки письма?

Answer (score 0):

у меня в переменной $this храниться объект класса MailTemplate. Вылечил тем, что в цикле каждый раз задаю его новый

```
        foreach ($recipient as $n => $user){
            foreach ($params as $key => $value){
                if($n === $key) {
                    $mailer = self::getEmailTemplates($event_code, $informing); // <-- добавлено
                    $mailer->sendMail($user->email,$params[$n]);
                    usleep(200000); // задержка на 0,2сек для отправки не более 5 писем в секунду
                }
            }
        }
```

getEmailTemplates создаёт объект MailTemplate.

вылечить то вылечил, но всё равно осталось неясным то, почему в новые итерации цикла функция sendMail заходила не "чистой", а тянула данные из предыдущей итерации.

Comment: Смотря в каком контексте был запущен цикл. Если в контексте объекта, то вот и ответ.